Why do i get "Invalid plugin.yml"
Hello i want to create my first plugin but i have been running into a problem with the invalid plugin
here is my code
I am using Gradle Minecraft 1.20.4
Error :
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:170) ~[spigot-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:157) ~[spigot-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:121) ~[spigot-api-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:430) ~[spigot-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:4090-Spigot-b754dcc-38b1f49]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.e(DedicatedServer.java:223) ~[spigot-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:4090-Spigot-b754dcc-38b1f49]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1000) ~[spigot-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:4090-Spigot-b754dcc-38b1f49]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:4090-Spigot-b754dcc-38b1f49]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml


I tired looking at other question and other forms but couldnt find anything that worked

Please consider including a minimal reproducible example instead of a link to your code.

What does your plugin.yml look like?

You're link return a 404 for us

Now try looking at the github page please try again i think i fixed the 404 problem
https://github.com/MoScripts/custom_plugin

why does it say
"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
"

never mind i fixed it by adding the plugin.yml in the jar file

Your file plugin.yml must be located at the root of your project.
In your repository, this file is located in the subfolder resources.
